# Flutter relational database project

Tags: flutter

Can I implement a student portal a mobile based application,using sqflite flutter in which teachers can access student table records and similarly the admin can access every table,it means a kind of relational database between every entity?

Comment: The answer to your question is most likely "yes, it's possible" but describing every detail of that step is way too broad for a stackoverflow question. Stackoverflow is more a Q&A site for specific programming questions than a "How to" or tutorial site

Answer (score 0):

Sqflite is a database stored on the users individual phone if you want to do something like a student portal you need a real time database which will ensure that others users will be in sync, you can do this by creating a backend application using node.js,java or python and connect it with a relational database such as postgress, mysql and then connect it to your flutter application via http request, another alternatives is to use firebase